# How to transfer a float value between View Controllers with Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, getter-setter

I have 1 original tab, tab A, which contains a button to segue to a second ViewController (B). In VC B, a number is selected and changes a label in Tab A to say that number (All of that works perfectly).

I have a method that makes a new tab, and I need to know how to get the float value from Tab A and VC B to be recognized as the same value in Tab C (the new tab). Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Here is the method I have to make a new tab

```
    -(void)makeNewTab: (NSString *)linkToSnipe {

NSMutableArray* tabs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tabs addObjectsFromArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
NewLinkViewController* newVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Link"];
[tabs addObject: newVC];
UITabBarItem* item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
NSString* itemTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Link # %lu", (unsigned long)[itemsAlreadyAddedToCart count]];
[item setTitle: itemTitle];
[item setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shoe.png"]];
[newVC setTabBarItem:item];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers: [NSArray arrayWithArray:tabs]];
int indexOfNewTab = [tabs count]-1;
[newVC setLinkToSnipe:linkToSnipe];
[newVC setSizeIWant: sizeChosen];
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = indexOfNewTab;
```

}

setLinkToSnipe:linktosnipe works perfectly, that string is known as the same thing in the new tab.
setSizeIWant: sizeChosen does not work. Size chosen is the float value I need in tab C

Comment: Are these "tabs" controllers in a tab view controller? What button are you talking about that segues from tab A to tab B? One of the tab bar buttons (there is no segue when going between controllers embedded in a tab bar controller, so I don't understand what you're talking about)?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's a bit hard to make a suggestion other than to do it the same way you are doing it now between tabs A and B. When you create tab C, give it a property that gets set by whatever creates it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to have a float value in tab C :

```
@property (nonatomic) float floatValue;
```

and change it by adding the following at the end of tab B and tab A:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue"]){
        ViewCont *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.floatValue = value;
    }

}
```